# How to expose and call methods on MVC 4 user controls

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am converting my asp.net site to MVC 4.  My site has a control called loginbox that prompts the user for username and password.  The control also exposes a method called IsLoggedIn that a hosting page can call.  I want to continue to encapsulate the login logic in my loginbox control and call it in a similar fashion from a parent level page (i.e loginBoxInstance.IsLoggedIn()).  How do I do that?

Comment: MVC does not have user controls.  You should use action filters or a base controller class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MVC doesn't have a concept of user controls. The whole setup of MVC is to separate logic from the view. You could achieve a similar setup by creating a separate controller and a partial view.

Then in your main view you could call RenderAction on the controller, which renders the partial view. However, this is only valid for the rendering stage, so something like IsLoggedIn() is not something you can (or should) do in MVC.

Example:

**Controller**

```
public class LoginController
{
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        return PartialView();
    }
}
```

**Partial View**

```
// Place this file in Views/Login/Login.cshtml
<div>
   <!-- Your markup -->
</div>
```

**Main view**

```
@Html.RenderAction("Login", "Login")
```

This will allow you to separate the view part (and also the logic) of the login rendering into a separate controller and view, which can be included in another view.

However, what you probably want is something like Action-attributes or inherit from a base controller class which handles all this for you.

The paradigm of MVC versus Web Forms is very different, and I think you should look into a more appropriate way of doing this.

Comment: I disagree with the render action option since you would be making an additional HTTP request every time you hit every page that contains your render action. It is better to look at the default MVC project and see how they do it with simple membership, login controller and partial views.

Comment: RenderAction does not create an additional HTTP request, it just invokes the action on the controller within the same request

Comment: I tried this out myself and you are correct. There is no additional HTTP request fired. I stand corrected.